# Joining table on two columns only joins it on a single

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I correctly join a table on two columns. My issue is that the result is not correct as it only joins on a single column.

This question started of in this other question: [SQL query returns product of results instead of sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423284/sql-query-returns-product-of-results-instead-of-sum?noredirect=1#comment112155807_63423284) . I am creating a new question as there is an other issue I am trying to solve.

I join a table of materials on a table which contains multiple supply and disposal movements. Each movement references a material id. I would like to join the material on each movement.

My query:

```
SELECT supply_material_refer, disposal_material_refer, material_id, material_name
FROM "construction_sites"
         JOIN projects ON construction_sites.project_refer = projects.project_id
         JOIN addresses ON construction_sites.address_refer = addresses.address_id
         cross join lateral ( select *
                              from (select row_number() over () as rn, *
                                    from supplies
                                    where supplies.supply_project_refer = projects.project_id) as supplies
                                       full join (select row_number() over () as rn, *
                                                  from disposals
                                                  where disposals.disposal_project_refer = projects.project_id
                              ) as disposals
                                                 on (supplies.rn = disposals.rn)
    ) as combined
         LEFT JOIN materials material ON combined.disposal_material_refer = material.material_id
    OR combined.supply_material_refer = material.material_id
WHERE (projects.project_name = 'Project 15')
ORDER BY construction_site_id asc;
```

The result of the query:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| supply_material_refer  | disposal_material_refer | material_id | material_name |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|                    1  | 1                       |          1  | Materialtest  |
|                    2  | 1                       |          1  | Materialtest  |
|                    2  | 1                       |          2  | Dirt          |
|                    1  | 1                       |          1  | Materialtest  |
|                    2  | 1                       |          1  | Materialtest  |
|                    2  | 1                       |          2  | Dirt          |
|                    1  | (null)                  |          1  | Materialtest  |
|                    4  | (null)                  |          4  | Stones        |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

An example line I have issues with:

```
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| supply_material_refer  | disposal_material_refer | material_id | material_name |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|                     2  |                      1  |          1  | Materialtest  |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

A prefered output would be like:

```
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| supply_material_refer  | supply_material_name | disposal_material_refer | disposal_material_name |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
|                     2  | Dirt                 |                      1  | Materialtest           |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

I have created a sqlfiddle with dummy data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/863d78/2

To my understanding the solution would be to have a disposal_material column and and supply_material column for the material names. I do not know how I can achieve this goal though...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A question should be self contained - a fiddle is an added (and welcome!) bonus. So please **[edit]** your question and include the full query you have trouble with as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: Not wishing to appear rude, but how does someone who asks a question like "how do I join a pair of tables on two columns" (i.e. a database 101 level question) go and write a multi-subquery-level analytical/window function equipped query that makes use of a range of inner and outer joins and also has a cross apply?

Comment: @Caius Jard: If it is such a trivial question I would love some hints. I do only know the DB basics but I was not able to solve this issue.

Comment: Er, ok. Here's how you join a table on two columns `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b`. A join predicate is simply a truth statement; you add more columns by appending more boolean-resulting statements

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it did not solve my issue. Could you show me how your solution should work on my example? Also your example joins two independant columns of two tables. My issue is two tables joining on the same referenced column.